# @Resource injection value null on a RESTEasy resource

Tags: java, jax-rs, code-injection, resteasy

I am trying to use the @Resource annotation within my JAX-RS resource (using RESTEasy 3.0.5.Final implementation). The `InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/testString")` retrieves the `Hello World` from the web.xml file correctly. But the return value of this resource sends back a `Value of hello:null`. The @Resource does not seem to instantiate the `hello` field at all. I am running this using Maven Jetty Plugin 6.1.15.

My Resource:

```
@Path("config")
public class ConfigurationResource {

    private String hello;

    @Resource(name="testString")
    public void setHello(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getResouces() throws NamingException{
        System.out.println((String)InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/testString"));
        return String.format("Value of hello:%s", hello);
    }

}
```

My web.xml

```
<web-app>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.yatin.rest.boot.ShoppingApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>testString</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>Hello World</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>

</web-app>
```

Does anyone know why a null value is being returned i.e. the @Resource is not working correctly and how to resolve this?

I did have a look at this ["env-entry is not injected with @Resource annotation into CDI beans and JAX-RS resources"](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2368) but the ticket seems to be marked as Resolved.

Comment: I think the problem is to do with CDI. The Jetty out of the box needs an implementation of CDI like [JBoss Weld.](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/framework-weld.html)